# Recording a wav file using GNU Radio instead of other software

Tags: gnuradio

I originally made this flow diagram to process signal in real time from cubesats that have a cent-freq of 437 MHz, but I want to record signals to anaylize later the wav file so   . However, I want to know if the process to record a wav file is correct. Can you give some advice to know if my flow graph is good? Do I need a resampler? The goal is to anaylize later the wav file recorded. I know that this process can be done with SDR# or other but I want to know if this is also possible with GNU Radio.

Her is my diagram to record a wav file:

[image]

And here is my original diagram to analyze in real time signals:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is perfectly possible to save signals to WAV files in gnuradio; I've done it many times.

Just make sure that the sampling rate you specify is correct. If recording a quadrature signal, specify a WAV file with two channels.

Regarding your flowgraphs, I don't see why you need a quadrature demodulator in one but not the other. I'd just replace the "satellite decoder" with a 2-channel WAV file sink.

Comment: Great thanks! I will try to use WAV file two channels.

The reason for using satellite decoder in the second flowgraph is that I will decode in real time as the cubesat passes over. 

The first flowgraph is for recording the signal for future analysis for other students

Comment: I took your advice and created a two channel wav file sink: https://imgur.com/a/EkQ20tt

However, I am not sure if the connection is good. Sometimes I see post using a complex to float block diagram. Is the complex to float equivalent to the quadrature demod or is my set up already ok?

Comment: Not quite -- If the signal you want to record is real, then one channel is enough. If it is complex, then you need a "complex to float" block, which has two outputs, and a 2-channel audio sink. The choice depends on the point in the flowgraph at which you wish to record the signal. In the flowgraph in your comment above, the signal out of the quadrature demod block is real, so one channel suffices.